# The XYZ industrial group is a manufacturer of.. (the manufacturer of..)

Tags: articles

Two possible ways to translate a sentence from a corporate website:

> The XYZ industrial group is **the** manufacturer and purveyor of a wide range of gas separators and compressors.

or:

> The XYZ industrial group is **a** manufacturer and purveyor of a wide range of gas separators and compressors.

Wouldn't the first sentence mean the Group is the Universe's sole manufacturer of this kind of equipment? Or maybe both sentences are acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly read, 'The manufacturer' suggests that they are the sole creator of a wide range of gas separators and compressors. Other manufacturers do not make whatever has been defined as a 'wide range' of those products. (Note: These other manufacturers might still make gas separators and compressors, just not 'a wide range' of them).

Needless to say, outside of a very, very, *very* select group of niche industries, this statement is going to be incorrect, even before you get down to debating what constitutes a 'wide range'.

Therefore, we can safely say that the manufacturer is one of many making wide ranges of gas separators and compressors, and are **a** manufacturer, not *the* manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

They both seem correct to me!

In the first sentence, we are talking about ***the XYZ*** group. I mean after defining the group, we are defining their industrial activity. Let's put some company's name and it'll make it clear.

> *The ArcelorMittal group is the manufacturer of steel and its products.*

Since you are talking about *steel and its products*, I think it is acceptable. I have often read the CEOs statements reading, *"We are the manufacturer of wireless modems."* So, when the things that they manufacture are *generalized*, I think the definite article is *okay.* Needless to say, when we are talking about one and the only product, we certainly use the definite article as you have already put your doubt. The Coca Cola Company is **the** manufacturer of Sprite.

On the other hand,

> *TransAKT is a manufacturer of highly innovative agricultural equipment*

seems to be common practice as found on [CNNMoney](http://money.cnn.com/news/newsfeeds/articles/globenewswire/10101650.htm).